# How much hotmail capacity do I have?

Tags: outlook.com

How do I find out how much free space do I have in hotmail?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft states that your inbox capacity will grow as you need. Originally, you start with [**5GB**](http://www.windowslive.com/Tutorial/Hotmail/Storage/StepByStep) before Hotmail begins it's expansion. See [Storage limits in Hotmail](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/hotmail/email-storage-about-ui) for more info.

Comment: How do I find how much capacity do I have available _now_?

Comment: Comes standard with 5GB, I just included a link in my original reply.

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Comment: No. I don’t know how much am I using _now_.

Comment: I just created a Hotmail account, just to find that info for you, and from what I see, they don't display current storage usage. Which makes sense, because its unlimited and isn't relevant.

Comment: @BrianDillingham - It was/still is relevant to kinokijuf, and is now relevant to me as I got a warning a few days ago that extra space was being allocated, but that it would take a few days, and last night first couldn't store a 10Mb sent e-mail, then couldn't send something a 1/10 of that size to myself (postmaster notification of delivery failure). I doubt MS would use the term "unlimited" (seeing as it is an absolute, and people love to abuse privileges), though I am sure someone will find a evidence someone slipped up by using it somewhere on the internet.

Comment: I doubt I am anywhere near 5Gb even, but a display of how much one is using (regardless of the situation with storage limits) is helpful in a number of situations I can think of (Backing up one's mailbox is a good example). I mean there isn't even any display of how big an individual e-mail is (I for one send 100's of lines of text sometimes). Lastly, if you feel that the OP's question was irrelevant, why did you answer it?